# Looping thread arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a simple loop over a String array which then passes the String to a threadlist method. However I can't seem to print out both String's. It just prints the second name `"Fred"` which makes me think that I am overwriting the first String with the second String. How can I make the `ArrayList` include both Strings `"Tim"` and `"Fred"`?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Threads extends Thread implements Runnable{

    private ArrayList threadList;
    private String e;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] elements = {"Tim","Fred"};    
        Threads t = new Threads();
        for (String e: elements) {           
            t.threadL(e); 
        }
        //loop over the elements of the String array and on each loop pass the String to threadL

        for (int index = 0;index<t.threadList.size();index++){
            System.out.print(t.threadList.get(index));
        }
        //loop over the threadList arraylist and printout
    }

    public ArrayList<String> threadL(String e) {
        threadList = new ArrayList<>();
        threadList.add(e);
        return(threadList);
    }
}
```

Comment: `threadList = new ArrayList<>();` what do you think happens here? Especially when you call `threadL` a second time?

Comment: Where are you implementing Runnable?

Comment: You are making a new `ArrayList` every time `threadL` is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The direct solution to your problem is that you are instantiating the `threadList` variable each time the method `threadL` is invoked. So on the second call, whatever was stored before is disregarded and the new content is added:

```
public ArrayList<String> threadL(String e) {
    threadList = new ArrayList<>(); // <-- instantiates a new list each time it is called
    threadList.add(e);
    return threadList;
}
```

You should instantiate that list only once, for example where it is declared. Also, you definitely should not use raw types like `List` but always the typed version:

```
private List<String> threadList = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

Note that in the given example, you are actually not using any `Thread` or `Runnable` feature (since you did not override `run()` or started the thread). Also, [prefer implementing `Runnable` over extending `Thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/541487/1743880).

Comment: Thanks for this, i removed threadList = new ArrayList<>(); and declared private List<String> threadList = new ArrayList<>(); initially

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a new array list each time you go through  loop. That's why you can't see element[0], since it's replaced with new list.